# California Primary Elections Absentee Ballot 2016

Tags: united-states, election, california

I was Wondering if anyone has received their California Primary Elections Absentee Ballot yet? i spend a good 30 minutes searching  online for a date of when they actually mail these ballots to voters but could not find a source.

Comment: Have you tried the [Secretary of State](http://www.sos.ca.gov/elections/voter-registration/vote-mail/) page?

Comment: What is the question?  Do you want to know if anyone has received their ballots yet? or the date that they're supposed to mail the ballots?

Comment: You can try to call local election commission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [Secretary of States](http://www.sos.ca.gov/elections/upcoming-elections/june-7-2016-presidential-primary-election/key-dates-and-deadlines-june-7-2016/) office for your state for important election deadlines. Ballots will be mailed out at near the beginning of May.

> Voter Information Guide Mailing Period    April 28 - May 17, 2016
>
> Vote-By-Mail Ballot Mailing Period    May 9 - May 31, 2016